# Trouble with list adapters and images. Android

Tags: android, image, listview

i need help with this wall i have hit inside my app.  Basically i have a screen that needs to display 80 rows of information (scrollable listview type) however i need 2 different images (dependent upon data from the database);

like this (image edit; it wont let me post images so i'll ASCII draw it, prolly wont turn out right =) )

---

|img| |  img 2   |   Built String
|***| |*__*_*__**|

Where the first image is say like a picture of a person, the second image will be sorta like a progress bar made up 1 of 5 pictures (20% increments) and the text will be a string built from data.

I can get my listviews to display a built string perfectly but im having issues on the images.  Anyway, ive searched and cant seem to find any information to help so if anyone is out there that can help me id appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a special xml layout file for the single row which then contains
all the `<Image>` tags for what you want.

Have a look at https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/res/layout/tweet_list_item.xml for an example. This layout is then passed when setting the adapter as in https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TweetListActivity.java#L419